# How to identify the clicked button belongs to which listbox item?

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF programming, I have a problem to write the button click event handler. Because the button is inside a listbox item(a part of datatemplate), and when the button is clicked, I can't tell which item it belongs to. Is there any solution? SOS - -

Comment: Depends, have you defend a generic Click Handler as an attached event on the ListBox? Or do you have a click event handler on each ListboxItem? Anyway, in the event the sender object or in the RoutedEventArgs the Source property should be your clicked item.

Comment: We can better help you if you provide some code or explain how are you doing this.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that you have bound a list box to a collection, and your buttons are part of your Data Template or Item Template.
You can bind the `Tag` property of the buttons to your data object:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type c:Person}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock>Name:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Tag="{Binding Path=.}">Click me!</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the click event:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    Person p = (Person)b.Tag;
    MessageBox.Show(p.Name);
}
```

But, as other people suggest, you can use the `DataContext` property of the Button. It already points to the `Person` object in my example.

I think by using the `Tag` property, you have more control over what you want to access in you event handler.

There are many ways to do everything! Choose the one that best suits you.

Comment: thx for your explaination and code and I have fixed my problem.

Comment: By the way, what is the tag property generally about?

Comment: It is used to store some custom user data in controls. All of the controls of WPF and WindowsForms have this property. By the way, the DataContext property of the button already point to the exact same object.

Answer (score 3):

You can get that information from the `DataContext`.

```
public class Person {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

}

 Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>() {

      new Person() { Name = "John", Age = 30 },
      new Person() { Name = "Tim", Age = 48 }
 };

 lbPersons.DataContext = Persons;

 private void person_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        Button cmd = (Button)sender;
        if (cmd.DataContext is Person) {
            Person p = (Person)cmd.DataContext;
        }
    }
```

And in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserTemplate" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="50"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Age}" Width="20"/>
            <Button Content="Click" Click="person_Clicked"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Name="lbPersons" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserTemplate}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

ListBox.selectedItem and listbox.SelectedIndex will be set as part of clicking the button.

Assuming the items in the list box are say type MyListBoxItem

```
void SomeButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ListBox lb = sender as ListBox
  if (lb != null)
  {
    MyListBoxItem item = lb.SelectedItem As MyListBoxItem;
    if (item != Null)
    {
      item.MethodRelatedToButton(); // maybe
    }
  }
}
```

Amplified as requested

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your words? can you explain more detailedly?

Comment: He meant, that the Listbox, where one of your children was clicked, also gets the SelectedIndex and SelectedItem property changed because of clicking on a child item. You can use these properties to see which item was clicked.